# How Spring modules internally use java?

Tags: java, spring

I have been working with Spring framework but wanted to know how and what concepts of Java it leverages to provide features like `Inversion of control`, `AOP` etc. Any useful article or other resource would be helpful.

Comment: It all boils down to the _Reflection API_.

Comment: If you're really, _really_ curious, why not skip the middleman and go straight to the source... literally.  The Spring Framework source code is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework)

Answer (score 1):

Spring uses `Reflecion` to inspect and instantiate the classes. Here's the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-introduction) that explains how classes are inspected and how instances/dependencies are created.

For Spring AOP, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-proxies)'s the link that states Spring uses J2SE dynamic proxies:

> Spring AOP defaults to using standard J2SE dynamic proxies for AOP
>   proxies. This enables any interface (or set of interfaces) to be
>   proxied.